# Indexing doesn't work in two nested loops

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, c-strings

I've been coding with Python about a year now, and decided to learn C as well. I was trying to write a function to reverse the given character array line by line (exercise from K&R). Here's the code:

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i, lastIndex, tempLetter1, tempLetter2;
    i = lastIndex = 0;
    while (s[lastIndex] != EOF) {
        while (s[lastIndex] != '\n') {
            i = lastIndex;
            tempLetter2 = s[i];
            while (s[i] != '\n') {
                tempLetter1 = tempLetter2;
                tempLetter2 = s[i + 1];
                s[i + 1] = tempLetter1;
                ++i;
            }
            ++lastIndex;
        }
        ++lastIndex;
    }
}
```

This ends up in an infinite loop. I inserted some printing code inside the second loop:

```
printf("s[0] = ");
putchar(s[0]);
printf("\ns[1] = ");
putchar(s[1]);
printf("\ns[2] = ");
putchar(s[2]);
```

And they all contained the first character of input array (`Hello World`).

```
s[0] = H
s[1] = H
s[2] = H
```

I also omitted the first while loop, and still didn't work. Although the indexing works fine outside the loop. The third loop also works.

I've put the whole code in case there are other aspects of it badly written, I'd appreciate it if pointed out :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 1000

void getLine(char[]);
void reverse(char[]);

int main() {
    char line[LEN];
    getLine(line);
    reverse(line);
    printf("\n%s\n", line);
    return 0;
}

void getLine(char s[]) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: There is a serious logical error in your code. Please check. Also, char array ends with '\0' not '\n'.

Comment: @denis Thanks for the response. Could you explain a bit more? I'm also checking for a new line with `'\n'`. Perhaps I should replace `EOF` with `'\0'`?

Comment: How do you define and initialise what is getting passed into `reverse()`?

Comment: I prototype it before `main()` with `void reverse(char[])`. I've also defined a function `getLine(char s[], int len)` which fills the given array with input characters using `getchar()`. I then call the function with `reverse(s)`.

Comment: Still, how is `s` defined?

Comment: @alk Thank you, I added the rest of the code.

Comment: Following this logic: `for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) ` an  `EOF` is *not* stored in the array `line`. So testing for it in `reverse()` is useless. `getline()` uses `s[i] = '\0';` to place a trailing `'\0'` as end-of-string marker, that is the `0`-terminator as needed to make the `char`-array `line` a C-"string".

Comment: Also this is the perfect opportunity to use a debugger.

Comment: @alk Thanks for the response, I changed to check for `'\0'`. Although the problem still exists.

Comment: there are numerous examples on stackoverflow.com of how to write a function that reverses a char string.  You can easily modify that code to perform the same action for each incoming char string.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) use meaningful variable names.  variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: the function: `getline()` has a problem.  it does not know the length of the input buffer.  So it can overrun the input buffer.  Suggest adding a parameter (or use a #define statement for the max buffer length) and have the loop in the `getline()` function check the current length against the max length at each iteration of the input loop.  specifically, the `LEN` macro.

Comment: to avoid `text replacement` errors, keep a habit of wrapping macro values in parens.

Comment: strongly suggest each input line be processed separately so calling `getline()` and `reverse()` in a loop,   Otherwise, what happens if the input is more than 1000 characters?  what happens if the user starts typing something else on the same terminal being used by the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code starts out with

```
while (s[lastIndex] != EOF) {
```

Given that there's no file-reading going on here, `EOF` (End Of File) is not correct. Did you mean `0`, meaning the end of the string? Or better yet, `'\0'` meaning the end of the string in character form? (Also called `NUL`, but that symbol isn't defined.)

Well, assuming that the first character of `s` isn't `EOF`, it then immediately enters a second loop:

```
while (s[lastIndex] != '\n') {
```

First thing: that won't check for `NUL` anymore. If you hit a `NUL`, it'll blaze straight past it... But assuming that the input string is well-formed, and its last character before the final `NUL` is a `'\n'`, let's keep going.

As I understand it, you want to reverse the characters in each line within the main string. That means that you need to remember the beginning of the line (good, that's in `lastIndex` - pity about the name), then go looking for the end of the line. You're using `i` for that...

Hang on: you're swapping characters as you go? Surely you should look for the end of the line, then start moving `lastIndex` and `i` closer and closer to each other, swapping as you go? So you should be incrementing `lastIndex` while *decrementing* `i`, inside the same loop.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you John, I agree, the algorithm may need some work... Although what's confusing me atm is the fact that `s[0]` and `s[2]` in the second loop are the same! I also removed the first loop (checks for `EOF` - which should be checking for `'\0'`) and the problem was still there.

Comment: If you're fiddling around with the loop as given in our original post, I don't understand what you're trying to do when you say "reverse". The code as given would turn "ABCDE" into "AABCD" - you never assign to `s[i]`.

Comment: Thanks again, I had missed the `s[lastIndex] = tempLetter2` after the third loop. I put it and worked... Although I still don't get why various indices returned the same value (both before and after the third loop)...